# SQL listener connection fluctuates between primary and Secondary

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2017, listener, azure-vm

We have SQL Server 2017 + CU11 Always On set up with one primary and a secondary replica. Suddenly we started facing issues where SQL Server AG listener connection started fluctuating between primary and secondary.

There are no error logs on SQL Server and System events. Also we have setup the AG on single subnet.

Below are the parameters configured for listener.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ClusterResource -Name "SQLListenerName" | Get-ClusterParameter

Object                        Name                          Value                         Type
------                        ----                          -----                         ----
SQLListenerName               Name                          SQLListenerName               String
SQLListenerName               DnsName                       SQLListenerName               String
SQLListenerName               Aliases                                                     String
SQLListenerName               RemapPipeNames                1                             UInt32
**SQLListenerName               HostRecordTTL                 1200**                          UInt32
**SQLListenerName               RegisterAllProvidersIP        0**                             UInt32
SQLListenerName               PublishPTRRecords             0                             UInt32
SQLListenerName               ResourceData                  {1, 0, 0, 0...}               ByteArra
SQLListenerName               StatusNetBIOS                 0                             UInt32
SQLListenerName               StatusDNS                     0                             UInt32
SQLListenerName               StatusKerberos                0
```

Additional information: Our servers are on Azure and SQL listener is configured with Azure ILB.

Comment: You have a single subnet with presumably a listener with a single IPv4 address, I would check the applications' connection string or for DNS issues as I don't believe it would be the listener at play here.

Comment: One other thing to look into, is if you have multiple instances on the server, and they are using tcp port 1433. The listener will not be able to work properly if it is also listening on port 1433 in that case, and you might connect to the secondary instead of the primary. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: We are simply trying to connect through SSMS. When we look for properties of connections (Listener), Sometime it shows primary server name and sometime it shows secondary server name even though no failover has happened.

Also to cross check the connection, we used powershell command "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance SQLListenerName -Query "sELECT @@sERVERNAME". Sometime this also returns the primary server name and sometimes secondary server name.

Note: We are trying to access the listener from multiple third party server from same domain.

Comment: @RandiVertongen We have only one instance.

Comment: It sounds like you have read only routing enabled, can you confirm and verify?

Comment: @SeanGallardy   We haven't configured the readonly routing. We have set the Readable secondary property  to 'Yes' and not 'Read-Inteant only'.

Comment: Then you'll need to look into your networking and see if there is any load balancer, DNS, or other issues going on. The listener only points to the primary and since you've stated you don't have read only routing setup then there is no way to get routed to the secondary through the listener. Period.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Additional information: Our servers are on Azure and SQL listener is configured with Azure ILB. Issue gets resolved for some period when we restart the secondary server, but reoccurs after some time.